# Inserting into Database using jSON

Tags: php, jquery, database, json

Trying to add content to my database using a form and JSON. My query runs fine through phpmyadmin, but for some reason my PHP file is unable to receive the information from my form.

(Please save me the typical "Don't use mysql functions".)

Chrome's Network Preview shows me this:

```
      data: null
      debug: "SQL query was: INSERT INTO linktb (catName, title, desc, URL) VALUES ('1', '', '', '');<br>SQL query failed <br>Other output: "
      retval: 2
```

Debugging of my update.php:

```
      {"retval":2,"data":null,"debug":"SQL query was: INSERT INTO linktb (catName, title, desc, URL) VALUES ('', '', '', '');
      SQL query failed 
      Other output: "}
```

HTML & JS:

```
      <form method="post" id="addURL" name="addURL" method="post">
            <select id="catList" name="catList">
            <option value="1">Milk</option>
            <option value="2">Coffee</option>
            <option value="3">Tea</option>
            </select><br />
            <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title"><br />
            <input id="desc" name="desc" type="text" placeholder="Description"><br />                
            <input id="URL" name="URL" type="text" placeholder="URL"><br />
            <input id="key" name="key" type="text" placeholder="Key"><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#addURL").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $("#addURL").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            catList: $("#catList").val(),
            title: $("#title").val(),
            desc: $("#desc").val(),
            URL: $("#URL").val(),
            key: $("#key").val(),
        };
    $.getJSON("update.php",form_data,function(data){
        switch(data.retval){
            case 0: $("#status").html("Unable to update!");
                    $("#status").css("background-color","red");
            break;
            case 1: $("#status").html("Update successful!");
                    $("#status").css("background-color","green");
            break;
            default: $("#status").html("Database error, please try again.");
                    $("#status").css("background-color","red");
            break;
        }
    });
});         
});
```

PHP:

```
$json = array("retval" => 2, "data" => NULL, "debug" => "");

$catList = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['catList']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']);
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['desc']);
$URL = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['URL']);
$key = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['key']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO linktb (catName, title, desc, URL) VALUES ('".$catList."', '".$title."', '".$desc."', '".$URL."');";

$json['debug'] .= "SQL query was: ".$sql."<br>";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    $json['debug'] .= "SQL query failed <br>";
    $json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    die(json_encode($json));
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    $json['retval'] = 0;
    $json['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
} else {
    $json['retval'] = 1;
}
$json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: You prevent the submission of the form with `preventDefault` - so the data never gets sent. Where is the code that sends the data?

Comment: It's true though, you shouldn't use them. People don't just say that for the heck of it, there's just absolutely no reason to use mysql anymore.

Comment: You can use jQuery's `serialize` instead of manually gathering your form data together. Might save you some time. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript & HTML I was using was fine, turned out I used the word "desc" in MYSQL which represented descending instead of the var that I wanted to use it as.

Answer (score 1):

Well taking a stab here. It doesn't seem that you are ever submitting your form. I assume you want to do this via ajax.

```
 $("#addURL").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //now what? try serializing your form and sending it via json
    $formData = $(this).serialize()
    $.ajax(url, {
        data : JSON.stringify($formData),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        type : 'POST'}
    );
 };
```

Comment: That gives me an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

Comment: It sounds like you cut and pasted the code without bothering to try and understand it. There is a variable called url. Did you try defining it with your website address?